# Microsoft Access Database Engine - Failure Creating File

Tags: vb.net, excel

I've installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine in order for an app to read and update and Excel file using OLEDB on a 64bit operating system. It all still works fine on 32 bit however i get a "Failure Creating File" error on a 64 bit machine.

I'm using the following connectionstring(VB.Net) as per connectionstrings.com(http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007):

```
lstrConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\excelfile.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install the 64-bit version.  Download [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en).

The generic solution is to force your program to run in 32-bit mode.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options, Target CPU = x86.